# Getting "Unfortunately, GluonMobile" stopped working

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am getting "Unfortunately, GluonMobile stopped working" every time I try to run my application on android. First of all, I am using gluon-mobile to make android apps that is writted in javafx (java) for GUI app development. I am also using the latest version of Intellij Idea while I am writing this question.

I searched on the internet, but I found no solutions. The problem is that Gluon mobile does not have that much support I guess. The installation was done in many ways, through a USB debugging feature that I allowed in my phone, and through uploading my app to the internet and installing it successfully, both gives me the same result.

However, I used a tool that comes with the android sdk, called adb. When I opened the program, I got all of these massages :

```
01-25 18:37:01.532   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:01.532   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0x900,
proUsg=0x900,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:01.534  1860  2041 D mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_wins
ys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_bu
ffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
01-25 18:37:01.536  1134  9084 D WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{6c51
961 u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLa
uncher} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
01-25 18:37:01.541  1610  3016 D HwRecentsLockUtils: Search
01-25 18:37:01.541  1812 32608 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
01-25 18:37:01.541  1812 32608 I MediaProcessHandler: playingUids:
01-25 18:37:01.542  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping, home or recents stac
k task: TaskRecord{f7d8d1c #1 A=com.huawei.android.launcher U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
01-25 18:37:01.542  1610  1610 D BarTransitions.HwNavigationBarView: MODE_TRANSP
ARENT -> MODE_TRANSLUCENT animate=false
01-25 18:37:01.542  1610  1610 D BarTransitions.HwNavigationBarView: applyModeBa
ckground oldMode=MODE_TRANSPARENT newMode=MODE_TRANSLUCENT animate=false
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:act=android.de
viceinfo.chooser.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10800000 hwFlg=0x100 pkg=com.android.settin
gs cmp=com.android.settings/.deviceinfo.UsbConnModeChooserActivity
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:flg=0x10804000
 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity bnds=[48,1369][1032,2857]
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:act=android.in
tent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/downloads/gluonmo
bile-singleviewprojectapp.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x
10800003 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.In
stallStart
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:flg=0x58800000
 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageWarningD
ialog
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:act=android.in
tent.action.DELETE dat=package:com.gluon flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.google.android.p
ackageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:act=android.in
tent.action.DELETE dat=package:com.kaspersky.safekids flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.goo
gle.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1161 D ActivityManager: Skipping intent:flg=0x10800000
 cmp=com.android.systemui/.usb.HwUsbDebuggingActivity
01-25 18:37:01.548  1134  1403 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window callers
=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked:6591 com.andro
id.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2041 com.android.server.wm.Sessio
n.remove:218
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    : Exception occurred while getting Sett
ingsStore instance.
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionExcepti
on: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: BadAuthentication
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTa
sk.report(FutureTask.java:123)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTa
sk.get(FutureTask.java:207)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at awhm.b(:com.google.android.gm
s@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):3)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at awhm.a(:com.google.android.gm
s@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):8)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at awdx.a(:com.google.android.gm
s@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):9)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at awdx.a(:com.google.android.gm
s@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):27)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at aaum.run(:com.google.android.
gms@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):7)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at blwm.run(:com.google.android.
gms@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):2)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at tfd.b(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):15)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at tfd.run(:com.google.android.g
ms@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):10)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
olExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
olExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at tld.run(Unknown Source:7)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.j
ava:784)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    : Caused by: com.google.android.gms.aut
h.UserRecoverableAuthException: BadAuthentication
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzr.a(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):8)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzw.a(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):5)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzw.c(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):2)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzw.b(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):1)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzw.b(:com.google.android.gms
@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):2)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at gzw.f(Unknown Source:20)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at awhy.call(:com.google.android
.gms@19831021@19.8.31 (040408-284611645):3)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTa
sk.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-25 18:37:01.558  2071  4433 E awhm    :      ... 6 more
01-25 18:37:01.563   654   654 I GRALLOC :       shrFd=10,fmt=0x1,intFmt=0x20000
0001,btStrd=4352,size=9547776,pid=654
01-25 18:37:01.563   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:01.563   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0xb00,
proUsg=0xb00,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:01.573  1134  4786 D WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{2680
79f u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLa
uncher} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
01-25 18:37:01.581  1860  1860 V InputMethodManager: Reporting focus gain, witho
ut startInput
01-25 18:37:01.584  4160  4160 W ThreadPoolDumper: Queue length for executor Eve
ntBus is now 11. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
01-25 18:37:01.585  4160  4311 W SessionLifecycleManager: Handover failed. Creat
ing new session controller.
01-25 18:37:01.585  1825  2000 I APwTrigger: no high cpu load
01-25 18:37:01.587  1134  1859 W ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcas
t com.huawei.intent.action.PG_THERMAL_MSG_ACTION from system 1825:com.huawei.pow
ergenie/1000 pkg com.huawei.powergenie
01-25 18:37:01.587  1825  2000 I BroadcastAdapter: send hight cpu load msg to th
ermal!
01-25 18:37:01.596  1845  1856 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEn
abled: subId=0 phoneId=0
01-25 18:37:01.597  1845  1856 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEn
abled: subId=0 retVal=false
01-25 18:37:01.597   654   654 I GRALLOC :       shrFd=10,fmt=0x1,intFmt=0x20000
0001,btStrd=4352,size=9547776,pid=654
01-25 18:37:01.597   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:01.597   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0xb00,
proUsg=0xb00,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:01.602   654   654 I GRALLOC :       shrFd=10,fmt=0x1,intFmt=0x20000
0001,btStrd=4352,size=9547776,pid=654
01-25 18:37:01.602   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:01.602   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0xb00,
proUsg=0xb00,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:01.613  1845  1856 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEn
abled: subId=0 phoneId=0
01-25 18:37:01.613  1845  1856 D PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEn
abled: subId=0 retVal=false
01-25 18:37:01.618  1134  9084 I HwNetworkPolicy: onTransact, code = 15
01-25 18:37:01.629  4160  4311 I StreamController: registerScope: nowcards-15-14
e01197-e49b
01-25 18:37:01.661  1134  1279 E ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: failed to
 find this proc
01-25 18:37:01.685  4160  4311 I MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [spea
kerMode: 0]
01-25 18:37:01.686  4160  4311 I AudioController: Created new AudioSource
01-25 18:37:01.687  4160  4160 W StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.
maxLines:1 lineCount:1
01-25 18:37:01.688  4160  4160 W StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.
maxLines:1 lineCount:1
01-25 18:37:01.690  4160 11637 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
01-25 18:37:01.690  4160 11637 I MultipleReaderAudioSrc: Using micInputStream
01-25 18:37:01.690  4160 11513 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting  SR : 16000
 CC : 16 SO : 1999
01-25 18:37:01.690  4160 11513 D HwCust  : Create obj success use class android.
media.HwCustAudioRecordImpl
01-25 18:37:01.690  4160 11513 E HwCustAudioRecordImpl: isOpenEC : false
01-25 18:37:01.691   721  2375 D AudioFlinger: event 162
01-25 18:37:01.692   721  2375 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() sourc
e 1999, samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10,session 1345, flags 0
01-25 18:37:01.693   661   661 I audio_hw_primary: update config period size 960

01-25 18:37:01.693   661   661 I audio_hw_primary: change channel_mask form 10 t
o AUDIO_CHANNEL_IN_STEREO
01-25 18:37:01.695   721  2375 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() retur
ns input type = 0
01-25 18:37:01.696  4160  4311 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
01-25 18:37:01.696   721  2375 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() role 0
 type 0 num_ports 0 ports 0x73728200a8
01-25 18:37:01.696   721  2375 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() got 0
ports needed 8
01-25 18:37:01.697   721  2375 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() role 0
 type 0 num_ports 8 ports 0x7370a14000
01-25 18:37:01.697   721  2375 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() got 8
ports needed 8
01-25 18:37:01.697  1134  1134 I AudioSystem-JNI: listAudioPorts AudioSystem::li
stAudioPorts numPorts 8 generation 336 generation1 336
01-25 18:37:01.697   721 12578 I AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0x7370ab300
0 tid=12578 ready to run
01-25 18:37:01.697   661   661 I audio_hw_primary: do_in_standby standby: 1, in_
device: 0
01-25 18:37:01.698   721   964 D AudioFlinger: event 162
01-25 18:37:01.698  1825  2000 D AudioState: SESSION_ID_NEW, containsKey, pid: 4
160, sessionId: 1345,uid: 10043
01-25 18:37:01.699   661   661 I audio_hw_primary: do_in_standby standby: 1, in_
device: 0
01-25 18:37:01.701  4160 11513 D AudioRecordPermission: AudioRecordPermission
01-25 18:37:01.701  4160 11513 I AudioRecordPermission: remindWithResult:false
01-25 18:37:01.701  4160 11513 I HwAudioRecordImpl: checkRecordActive
01-25 18:37:01.702   721   964 W HuaweiAudioFlinger: soundtrigger is now disable
 or not support, pls enable it first from setting
01-25 18:37:01.702   721   964 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: startInput() input 694
01-25 18:37:01.702   721   964 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: getNewInputDevice() sel
ected device 0x80000004
01-25 18:37:01.702   721   964 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: setInputDevice() input
694 device 80000004 force 1
01-25 18:37:01.707  1825  2000 I DeviceMonitor: Add AudioIn uid:10043 pid:-2
01-25 18:37:01.707   654   654 I GRALLOC :       shrFd=10,fmt=0x1,intFmt=0x20000
0001,btStrd=4352,size=9547776,pid=654
01-25 18:37:01.707   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:01.707   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0xb00,
proUsg=0xb00,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:01.707   661   661 D audio_hw_primary: in_set_parameters_no_lock inp
ut_source: 6, in_device: 0x80000004
01-25 18:37:01.707   661   661 D dsp_interface: dsp_set_source:source = 6
01-25 18:37:01.707   661   661 D dsp_soc : set source 6 succ
01-25 18:37:01.707   661   661 I dsp_common: dsp_common_set_source:source = 6
01-25 18:37:01.708   721   964 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: setInputDevice() create
AudioPatch returned 0 patchHandle 684
01-25 18:37:01.708   721   964 V SoundTrigger: setCaptureState(1)
01-25 18:37:01.708   721   964 V SoundTriggerHwService: setCaptureState 1
01-25 18:37:01.708   721   964 D APM_AudioPolicyManager: event 164
01-25 18:37:01.708   721   964 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: AudioPolicyManager::sta
rtInput() input source = 1999
01-25 18:37:01.708  4160 11513 I HwAudioRecordImpl: sendStateChangedIntent, stat
e=3
01-25 18:37:01.709  1134  1859 I HwSystemManager: pkgName = com.google.android.g
ooglequicksearchbox pid = 0uidOf3RdApk = 10043permType = 1permCfg=1
01-25 18:37:01.709  1134  1859 I BackgroundPermManager: pkgName: com.google.andr
oid.googlequicksearchbox,pid: 0 ,uidOf3RdApk: 10043 ,permType: 1 ,permCfg: 1
01-25 18:37:01.710   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: start_input_stream: adev->in_
device = 0, in->device = 0x4
01-25 18:37:01.710  1825  2000 I PGServer: report state:1 event type:1 pid:4160
uid:10043 pkg:null to pid: 1134
01-25 18:37:01.710  1825  2000 D AudioState: auido type:in state:start pid:4160
uid:10043
01-25 18:37:01.710   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: select_devices++ mode[0]
01-25 18:37:01.710  1553  6599 E HSM     : BMNCaller:is not PermissionEnabled.
01-25 18:37:01.710   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: input_source_id 0x4, output_d
evice_id 0x2
01-25 18:37:01.710   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: select_devices() devices 0x2
input src 6 output route none input route voice-rec-handfree-mic in_device 0x4
01-25 18:37:01.710  4160 11513 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started  SR : 16000
CC : 16 SO : 1999
01-25 18:37:01.711   661 12579 I dsp_common: dsp_common_control_algo:set device
= 0
01-25 18:37:01.711   721   964 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() role 0
 type 0 num_ports 0 ports 0x7372820050
01-25 18:37:01.712   721   964 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() got 0
ports needed 8
01-25 18:37:01.712   721  2393 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() role 0
 type 0 num_ports 8 ports 0x7372d0d000
01-25 18:37:01.712   721  2393 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: listAudioPorts() got 8
ports needed 8
01-25 18:37:01.712  1134  1134 I AudioSystem-JNI: listAudioPorts AudioSystem::li
stAudioPorts numPorts 8 generation 337 generation1 337
01-25 18:37:01.715 11521 11521 I karaoke.IntentReceiver: Intent received, action
=huawei.media.AUDIO_RECORD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, sender MediaRecorder, packageNa
me com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, state 3
01-25 18:37:01.715  1134  9084 V BroadcastQueue: Finished with ordered broadcast
 BroadcastRecord{4debeaf u0 huawei.media.AUDIO_RECORD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION}
01-25 18:37:01.721  4160  4160 W StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.
maxLines:1 lineCount:1
01-25 18:37:01.722  4160  4160 I chatty  : uid=10043(u0_a43) com.google.android.
googlequicksearchbox:search identical 1 line
01-25 18:37:01.722  4160  4160 W StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.
maxLines:1 lineCount:1
01-25 18:37:01.755   661 12579 I dsp_common: dsp_common_control_algo:set device
= 0
01-25 18:37:01.756   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: select_devices--
01-25 18:37:01.756   661 12579 I audio_hw_primary: start_input_stream OK. rate :
 48000, period_size : 960, channel : 2
01-25 18:37:01.756   661 12579 D dsp_interface: dsp_set_source:source = 6
01-25 18:37:01.756   661 12579 D dsp_soc : set source 6 succ
01-25 18:37:01.756   661 12579 I dsp_common: dsp_common_set_source:source = 6
01-25 18:37:01.778  4160  4311 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
01-25 18:37:01.875   776   776 E         : [E/capacity_limit_control] not demo v
ersion, not set power control prop!
01-25 18:37:01.991   661   661 I audio_hw_primary: usb_ext_get_parameters: check
 show hires (false)
01-25 18:37:01.991   721  2393 I hash_map_utils: key: 'typec_need_show_hires' va
lue: ''
01-25 18:37:01.991  1134  1134 I HwAudioService: check HiRes Icon false
01-25 18:37:01.992  1134  1134 W ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcas
t huawei.intent.action.hideHiResIcon from system uid 1000 pkg null
01-25 18:37:01.992  1134  1134 I HwAudioService: broadcastHiresIntent : false
01-25 18:37:01.993  1610  1610 D StatusBarIconController: setIconVisibility icon
 is null or visibility not change visibility=false
01-25 18:37:02.036  1860  2041 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer o
n View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-25 18:37:02.036  1860  2041 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer o
n View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-25 18:37:02.038   654   654 I GRALLOC :       shrFd=10,fmt=0x1,intFmt=0x20000
0001,btStrd=4352,size=9547776,pid=654
01-25 18:37:02.038   654   654 I GRALLOC :       yuv=2,w=1080,h=2160,Stride u=0
v=0,offset u=0 v=0
01-25 18:37:02.038   654   654 I GRALLOC :       iova_size=9547776,conUsg=0xb00,
proUsg=0xb00,    strd=1088,[afbc]HdrStrd=1088 PyldStrd=69632 Scrmbl=0,ionhnd = 1

01-25 18:37:02.757   747  3000 I Pged-IPgedBinderService: ****action is 2, pid n
um is 2***
01-25 18:37:02.757   747  3000 I Pged-Freezer: thawPids
01-25 18:37:02.758  1825  2068 D PgedBinderAdapter: unfrz ok, pid: [8960]
01-25 18:37:04.290  1134  1724 W Watchdog: hungtask: writing kick
01-25 18:37:04.294  1134  1289 I EventHub: EventHub monitor: no key events in th
e past 60s,
```

While executing the android gradle task to generate an apk file, I got no errors and the console was clear. I didn't find any "ERROR" words nor red text, only peaceful white text. However, I executed the "run" task on Intellij Idea, it worked out just fine and the code was executed correctly on my PC. I got no idea of what is happening.

Comment: Here is for the little support... Run `adb logcat` from a terminal while you run your app on your device and see what exceptions you get. Also, is your device using on Android 10?

Comment: @JoséPereda , no, my device is using Android 5.1 . Another thing, which terminal? I mean, where do I execute the ```adb logcat``` command? is it an SDK android tool?

Comment: Yes, `adb` is a tool that you can find under <android sdk>/platform-tools, plug your device and run it from a terminal.

Comment: @JoséPereda , I want to ask you something of you don't mind me. I saw a lot of nice answers that are related to android that you answered before. Where did you learn all of that about android?